# Shortest regex search and sum for integers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Given a text file including different text and integer numbers (text.txt), what's the shortest way of getting the sum of all the numbers out if it? I have:

```
import re

f = open('text.txt', 'r')
result = 0
for line in f.readlines():
    for value in re.findall('[0-9]+', line):
        result += int(value)
f.close()
print(result)
```

Which works, but I would like to understand what are the possibilities to make it shorter?

Comment: You could make it shorter but you're going to sacrifice readability along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one line code. Shortest I could find.

```
import re
print(sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+', open('text.txt').read())]))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review! This isn't Code Golf, so the goal on this site is to write *good* code, not necessarily *short* code. Also, answers are expected to make "at least one insightful observation about the code in the question". https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). It good practice to use with statement when working with  a file.

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = sum(map(int, re.findall(r'[0-9]+', f.read())))

print(result)
```

Comment: I doubt the regex is necessary. What is fileted out?

Answer (score 7):

`read` instead of `readlines` will read the whole file into a single string. Using the file within a [context](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Context_Managers) avoids calling `close()`. The [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) shortens the remaining loop. [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) does what you'd expect:

```
import re

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = sum(int(value) for value in re.findall('[0-9]+', f.read()))
print(result)
```

Comment: I think you missed a `sum` call.

Comment: Thx for attention. Corrected it ;)

Answer (score 2):

`\d` instead of `[0-9]` saves a little.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that *shorter* shouldn't be the goal in itself, unless you're golfing (in which case, you want to be on [Code Golf and Coding Challenges](//codegolf.stackexchange.com)).  A better criterion is to have the *simplest* code that achieves the desired aim.

A major contribution to simplicity is to replace the explicit close of `f` with a `with` block:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    # do the addition

# f is closed before we get here
```

Another simplification is to use `sum`/`map` as suggested in [styvane's answer](/a/126365/75307); however, it may be more efficient to read the file a line at a time rather than slurping the entire contents into memory if it's very long.

We could also make the code more efficient by compiling the regular expression just once.

Following that, we might want to make the code more *reusable* and *testable*.  I would separate into a function that does the summing but doesn't care where the stream comes from (file, pipe, socket, string), and have tests for that.  Then simply call it with the input file stream.

That reusable function including unit-tests looks like this:

```
import re

def sum_integers(stream):
    """Return the total of all the digit strings found in the input stream
    >>> from io import StringIO
    >>> sum_integers(StringIO(''))
    0
    >>> sum_integers(StringIO('1'))
    1
    >>> sum_integers(StringIO('-1'))
    1
    >>> sum_integers(StringIO('a1z'))
    1
    >>> sum_integers(StringIO('1-2'))
    3
    >>> sum_integers(StringIO('1-2\\n3.4'))
    10
    """
    digit_pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
    return sum(sum(map(int, digit_pattern.findall(line))) for line in stream)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

And we can use it very simply:

```
def print_sum_of_integers_from_file(filename):
    print(sum_integers(open(filename, 'r')))
```

That's not *shorter*, but it is *better* in the ways I've described (more efficient, flexible and maintainable).